# Token is null when trying to access the user

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I've a strange issue with the token in Symfony 3.

I inject the `security.token_storage` into an Twig extension of mine

```
app.twig_extension:
     class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\TwigExtension
     arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
     tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now, in the constructor, I want to get the user from the token.

```
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    /** @var User user */
    $token = $tokenStorage->getToken();
    //$user = $token->getUser();
    //dump($user);
    //$this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

Here's the issue. If I dump the `$token`, everything seems normal. Here's a dump from the token:

```
PostAuthenticationGuardToken {#637 ▼
  -providerKey: "main"
  -user: User {#396 ▶}
  -roles: array:1 [▶]
  -authenticated: true
  -attributes: []
}
```

But if I'm using `$token->getUser();` I will receive an error that I'm calling `getUser` on **null**

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>
> Call to a member function getUser() on null

This error will be shown in the Symfony profiler. Now if I'm removing the part `$token->getUser();` from my code and then reload the profiler, the user will be displayed.

I can't explain this behavior neither why the error about the **null** variable is thrown. Can somebody explain this to me please?

I've already tried to inject the whole container into the server and tried to get the user over the container, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see that error on the profiler is the profiler URL isn't behind the firewall so  getToken() has no authentication information and is null.

the PHPdoc for `getToken` function

```
/**
 * Returns the current security token.
 *
 * @return TokenInterface|null A TokenInterface instance or null if no authentication information is available
 */
    public function getToken();
```

make sure you check if the authentication information is available before you call `getToken()`

Comment: I only want to receive the user if there's an logged in user. Everything but the login, logout is set behind a firewall. It's not only a profiler error but also everything else e.g. the rendering of assets fails because of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the issue itself, but I've found a working workaround.

Instead of injecting the TokenStorage into the extension, I'm giving the user as an parameter for the function I want to use.

This is the call I'm doing in my twig template

```
{{ showUnreadMessages(app.user) }}
```

And my TwigExtension contains the following functions:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('showUnreadMessages', [$this, 'showUnreadMessages'])
    ];
}

public function showUnreadMessages(User $user)
{
    return $this->dbHandler->getCountUnreadMessages($user);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead to get the user

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Comment: I'm in an service, there's no container. To inject the container isn't recommended anyway. This code you've posted is the same as mine, with the only difference that you're going over the container and that you must have the container for that.

Comment: then maybe `PostAuthenticationGuardToken->getUser();`

Comment: Sorry, but I think you haven't really understand the question I've asked. The variable `$token` is an object of the class **PostAuthenticationGuardToken**, that's why **PostAuthenticationGuardToken** is shown in the dump of the variable `$token` I've posted in my question.